# How to make DownloadOperation from BackgroundDownloader resumable

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am adding in functionality to download a large file into my application using the `BackgroundDownloader`/`DownloadOperation` functionality.  I am using a `PushStreamContent` in a Web Api controller to serve the data that's being requested using a GET operation.

I have added in the `Accept-Ranges` header to the response that's received from the Web Api controller, however the `BackgroundDownloader` doesn't seem to be recognising and attempting to resume downloads.  If I call `DownloadOperation.Pause()` then `DownloadOperation.Resume()` then the download starts again from the start and doesn't attempt to resume.

In fact if I look in the `AC\BackgroundTransferApi` folder I can see the `.down_data` get deleted when I perform the pause.  Looking in the `down_meta` file I can see the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header is present and I can see it when looking at the request in Fidder.

What do I need to do on the server side to indicate to the `BackgroundDownloader` that it supports a resumable transfer?  The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation.aspx) documentation simply states `Note  Paused or incomplete download operations can only be resumed if the server accepts range-requests.` which I believe I have satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DownloadOperation` class has a property that tells you if the operations is resumable: `DownloadOperation.GetResponseInformation().IsResumable`

The file is not deleted from `AC\BackgroundTransferApi`, it is moved to `AC\Temp`.

The first HTTP response must include `ETag` and `Accept-Ranges` headers:

```
ETag: "123ABC"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

When an operations is resumen, the HTTP request will contain:

```
Range: bytes=23000000-
If-Range: "123ABC"
```

Next HTTP response should contain something like this:

```
ETag: "123ABC"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 23000000-499999999/500000000
Content-Length: 477000000
```

Comment: Brilliant, I was missing the ETag, adding that in works a treat. Ta very much