# DownloadOperation doesn't resume when accessed by HTTPS to Azure Website

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, azure-web-app-service

Following on from the question [How to make DownloadOperation from BackgroundDownloader resumable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405298/how-to-make-downloadoperation-from-backgrounddownloader-resumable) I've got a resumable download working fine locally.

I have completed my webservice and published it as an Azure Website.  There appears to be an issue when downloading using HTTPS - when using HTTP the download can be paused and resumed fine and it will carry on, however if I use HTTPS then the download starts again from the start every time I try to resume the download, either from using the Pause and Resume methods or by disabling the internet connection.

I'm connecting to the webservice using the *.azurewebsites.net url which has a valid SSL cert, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

How do I get resumable background downloads working when using HTTPS?

Comment: There should be no difference.

Comment: Feedback from Microsoft is that this is by design and that HTTPS is not supported for background download operations

Comment: Is it an Azure Websites limitation? Because I am able to resume downloads using an Azure VM. Use this root certificate: http://1drv.ms/1sUFbCc and then this URI: http://http2.cloudapp.net/?etag=123ABC&slow=50&length=500000000&buffersize=500000&filename=something.txt